# JS/jQuery - If statements without "return"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*this question has been updated.

I have a set of boxes which, when clicked open a div called `#expander`. In my code, after `#expander` is opened, and if another box is clicked, I check if the new box clicked is the same as the last box clicked. If it is the same, I close `#expander`, else I briefly close it and then open it again.

This is demonstrated with the this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tcuy08p/3/)

Here is the same code, in stackoverflow:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(e) {
  if (!$('#expander').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#expander').addClass('active');
    $('.basic-info').css('border-left', '1px solid black');
    activeBox = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#main').text(activeBox);
   console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
    return;
  }

  if ($('#expander').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#expander').removeClass('active');
    $('.basic-info').css('border-left', '0px solid black');
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== activeBox) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#expander').addClass('active');
      }, 256);
    }
    activeBox = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#main').text(activeBox);
   console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
    return;
  }
});
```

```css
#expander{
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: .75s ease-out;
}
#expander.active{
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
#closer{
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #707070;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#closer:hover{
  background-color: #606060;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0px;
}
.box{
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.basic-info{
  padding: 8px 16px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #47a;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="expander">
  <div id="closer" title="Close"><span>&times</span></div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
<div class="basic-info">
  <div id="box1" class="box">1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

**The above code works (although it does not look exactly how it looks in my final layout)** BUT what it does not do run this: `$('.basic-info').css('border-left', '1px solid black');` after the first time a box is clicked (when it opens the `#expander`

I realize the reason this is not working is that the JS code first adds the classes and styles, but then the next if statement *removes* the classes and styles. Also, I have to paste the following code two times:

```
$('#main').text(activeBox);
console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
return;
```

**Does anyone know a better way to layout my if statements so that code does not conflict? Also, is there a way to not need to use `return;`s?**

P.S. does anyone have a link to a good `if statement` **tricks** tutorial so that I can learn these things for the future?

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the code based on the current answers and have changed the JS to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(e) {
  if ($('#expander').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#expander').removeClass('active');
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== activeBox) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#expander').addClass('active');
      }, 256);
      activeBox = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
      return;
    }
    $('.basic-info').css('border-left', '0px solid white');
    return;
  }
  $('#expander').addClass('active');
  $('.basic-info').css('border-left', '1px solid white');
  activeBox = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
}
```

(it does the same thing, just laid out differently). **All I am trying to figure out now is just how I can write this without any of the `return;`s and also so I do not have to write `activeBox = $(this).attr('id'); console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);` twice (unless these things are impossible/unavoidable)**

thank you.

Comment: You could do `if (foo) { ... } else if (bar) { ... }`, where the second one is only executed if `foo` is falsy *and* `bar` is truthy.

Comment: An if statement tutorial? I'm not sure what that would be, just read about JS control structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the clean up part and get rid of repeated data, you can convert your js code to this

**Updated**

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/4h8jfgjb/4/)

```js
// target the #expander 
var Expander = $('#expander'),
  activeBox = '';

$(document).on('click', '.box', function(e) {
  //toggleClass means if #expander hasClass, remove it, if it
  //doesn't have the class, add it.
  Expander.toggleClass('active');
  // same for .basic info, we use toggle class, instead of
  // CSS hardcoded, thus we can toggle
  $('.basic-info').toggleClass('black-border-left');

  if ($(this).attr('id') !== activeBox) {
    Expander.removeClass('active');
    // to get rid of the delay for when one .box div is clicked for the first time
    // when activeBox = ''.
    if(activeBox !== ''){
      setTimeout(function() {
        Expander.addClass('active');
      }, 500);
    }else{
      Expander.addClass('active');
    }
    activeBox = $(this).attr('id');
  }
  $('#main').text(activeBox);
  console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
});
```

Comment: good idea! +1 from me. any way to not have to `toggleClass` `$('.basic-info.')` or is that just unavoidable by going with this method...

Comment: it depends on what you're trying to do with that `$('.basic-info');` but I don't know what's your ideal approach for it

Comment: Sorry had a typo in my code, was `toggleClass('.black-border-left')` instead of `toggleClass('black-border-left')`, I removed the extra dot. and updated the answer

Comment: okay, got it on the typo (NBD), IDK, I just didn't want to make one random extra class to add the black border but I guess it is not the end of the world...

Comment: oh, found one thing which bugs on the above code - the first time you click the box, `activeBox` is `null` so the if statement returns true. This is fine as it will still open the box, it just adds the setTimeout lag to open it... any way around this?

Comment: you don't have to write that `class`, but this is make it more flexible, if you like it, here's [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/4h8jfgjb/3/) with `('border-left', '1px solid black');`

Comment: This one is easy too, just changed this declare the var as empty string `activeBox = ''` , then make a check to see if it's empty add the `.active` to the expander immediately, if not empty, execute the `setTimeout` function.. [exampe fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/4h8jfgjb/4/)

Comment: Updated the answer with the second fix

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.box', function(e) {
  if (!$('#expander').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#expander').addClass('active');
    $('.basic-info').css('border-left', '1px solid black');
    activeBox = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#main').text(activeBox);
    console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
  } else if ($('#expander').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#expander').removeClass('active');
    $('.basic-info').css('border-left', '0px solid black');
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== activeBox) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#expander').addClass('active');
      }, 256);
    }
    activeBox = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#main').text(activeBox);
    console.log('activeBox = ' + activeBox);
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but this still does not change the fact that `$('.basic-info').css('border-left', '0px solid black');` is removed after you click on a different box...

Comment: Well. You got `$('.basic-info').css('border-left', '1px solid black')` on Click on unactive box, so obviously it overrides  `$('.basic-info').css('border-left', '0px')`